# ClassNotFoundException on simple HelloWorld

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception

I wrote this simple Hello World program:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

which is named "HelloWorld.java". Then I compile it from the cmd using: "javac HelloWorld.java" and obtain the class file. Once I run the command "java -Xdiag HelloWorld" I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.loadMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:760)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:655)
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?
The OS is W10 and I installed the jdk version 11.0.1.
Thank you.

Comment: missing information, what is your OS? what is the path of CLASSPATH?

Comment: does HelloWorld.class file generate after you run `javac HelloWorld.java`?

Comment: @Spara highly likely no.

Comment: Why are you passing -Xdiag when you are running the program?

Comment: @snr Why does the OS and CLASSPATH matter here?

Comment: @EugenCovaci it's the reason of Spara's question that the class file is not generated.

Comment: Thanks everyone, the problem was with CLASSPATH, I just added a "." in it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by modifying the CLASSPATH environmental variable, inserting "." in it, so that java searches for classes in the current working directory.

Answer (score -1):

Create your java class under a package name throw src folder.. I hope error will be solved